# Rasters in R - merge taking mean, excluding NAs. Overlay and Mosaic both giving funny results

Tags: qgis, raster, r, overlay, mosaic

I have a series of raster images, all derived from LandSat data, which give pixels a value of 1 if they are predicted to contain water, 0 otherwise. Many of these images are from the LandSat 7 ETM+ SLC-off, which means they contain bands of missing data (NAs). Note the exact position of those bands varies from image to image. What I want to do is, for each pixel, take the mean value, simply excluding NAs.

I have tried the following (where `water_rasters` is a list containing the individual images described above):

```
water_mean <- do.call(overlay, c(water_rasters, fun = mean, na.rm = T)
```

and

```
water_mean <- do.call(mosaic, c(water_rasters, fun = mean, na.rm = T)
```

When using the `overlay` function, it appears that all pixels where any of my input layers were NA are NA in the output, so the water_mean raster is almost entirely NAs.

When using the `mosaic` function, I'm not quite sure what it does but the final image is certainly not the mean - almost every pixel is either 0 or 1, with no intermediate values (where I would expect quite a few intermediate values, and I have even checked individual pixels from the inputs and some should definitely be intermediate). However, it does seem to cover the whole scene, and does not have bands of NA data. As I said, I can't tell exactly what `mosaic` is doing - the `water_mean` raster certainly is generated from the input data (I can make out rivers, lakes etc) but it's not the mean of all of them or even the mean of a subset of them.

Thoughts? Workarounds? (Would be happy to use QGIS instead, but want the solution to be easily scaled up and repeatable.)

EDIT
As per request, simple example:

```
raster1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),5,5))
raster2 <- raster(matrix(c(NA,NA,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),5,5))
raster3 <- raster(matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),5,5))
raster4 <- raster(matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),5,5))
raster5 <- raster(matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),5,5))

extent(raster1) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
extent(raster2) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
extent(raster3) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
extent(raster4) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
extent(raster5) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)

projection(raster1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
projection(raster2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
projection(raster3) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
projection(raster4) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
projection(raster5) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")


water_rasters<-list(raster1, raster2, raster3, raster4,raster5)

water_mean_overlay <- do.call(overlay, c(water_rasters, fun = mean, na.rm = T))

water_mean_mosaic <- do.call(mosaic, c(water_rasters, fun = mean, na.rm = T))
```

In this example, `water_mean_mosaic` IS the desired output raster, where as `overlay` doesn't work (has NAs in the two top-left cells, where `raster2` is NA).

So I guess the problem isn't my code per se... Could the problem with mosaic be due to large numbers of large files? I'm talking about ~100 LandSat images, each 7011x7611 pixels...

Comment: Can you supply code to create a few sample tiny rasters (5x5?) that illustrate the problem? Just put, zeroes, ones and NAs in the right place and tell us what the output should be.

Comment: Yep - will edit post

Comment: Mosaic is for combining rasters with different, albeit overlapping, extents. The function you supply to it is supposed to be used in cases where multiple rasters overlap. All the rasters in your example have the same extent, so that is why it's providing the expected answer. I think the use of `overlay` in this case is unnecessary. Do all of the rasters in your real dataset have the same extents? If so, all you need to do is `mean(raster1, raster2, raster3, raster4, raster5, na.rm=T)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem with:

```
water_mean_overlay <- do.call(overlay, c(water_rasters, fun = mean, na.rm = T))
```

is that `na.rm=T` is being passed to `overlay`, and the help for `overlay` doesn't show an `na.rm` argument, so it is probably getting gobbled into the ... argument and then I'm not sure what's happening to it. Maybe it gets treated as another raster of all "TRUE" values? Or it just gets lost. Anyway...

The fix is to write a function that wraps `mean` but passes `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
> mean_narm = function(x,...){mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)}
> water_mean_overlay <- do.call(overlay, c(water_rasters, fun = mean_narm))
> plot(water_mean_overlay,col=rainbow(4))
```

but beware that `mean_narm(c(NA,NA))` is `NaN`, and that might not be expected, and you might want to set all `NaN` back to `NA` in your results raster.